# resolving promises in a sequential order using javascript / react from contentful CMS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise, contentful

I am trying to fetch a series of data from a contentful CMS sequentially, and once this is done intialize my React app. I can tell I'm not resolving these promises correctly, and am hitting a race condition, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

Given the following:

```
this.contentfulClient.getEntry('4KGFPDFY2MZrRWCi4hZj2g')
  .then((entry) => {
    //console.log(entry);
    dataStore.siteData = entry.fields;
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.contentfulClient.getEntries({
      content_type: 'visionsData'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        let visionsArr = [];
        response.items.map((vision) => {
          return visionsArr.push(vision.fields);
        });
        dataStore.visionsData = visionsArr;
        console.log('visions');
      })
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.contentfulClient.getEntries({
      content_type: 'inspirationsData'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        //console.log(response.items);
        let inspirationsArr = [];
        response.items.map((inspiration) => {
          return inspirationsArr.push(inspiration.fields);
        });
        dataStore.inspirationsData = inspirationsArr;
        console.log('inspirations');
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('data loaded');
        this.setState({
          dataLoaded: true,
        })
      })
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

I want to make sure that I first grab entry `4KGF...` then add it to the data store, then get the `visionsData` entries, then add them to the dataStore, then get the `inspirationsData` entries, then add them to the dataStore, then set the state of my app to `dataLoaded: true` as the last thing. Once that state is set, I should render my app, as follows:

```
render() {
  const { dataLoaded } = this.state;

  if (!dataLoaded) {
    return (<div>LOADING</div>)
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/inspiration" component={Inspiration} />
        <Route exact path="/redesign" component={Redesign} />
        <Route exact path="/visualize" component={Visualize} />
        <Route exact path="/confirmation" component={Confirmation} />
        <Reset />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

But what is happening is that sometimes one piece of the data set will render before the others, say (`inspirationsData`) and so `dataLoaded` will be set to true even though `visionsData` has not yet been added to the data store. I know that I could nest each individual `getEntries` call inside the previous `then((response))` call, but then I would get the sort of pyramid of nested promises structure that I'm trying to avoid. How do I avoid that and structure my promises properly?

Comment: This can be achieved with a straightforward promise chain comprising an inital call and just three sequential `.then()`s - no nested chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a promise to `then()` when operations within it are asynchronous and you want the chain to execute  sequentially.

Without a `return`, or when the return is not a promise, the `then()` resolves immediately regardless of whatever asynchronous operation is invoked inside it

Starting example only:

```
this.contentfulClient.getEntry('4KGFPDFY2MZrRWCi4hZj2g')
  .then((entry) => {
    //console.log(entry);
    dataStore.siteData = entry.fields;
  })
  .then(() => {
     return this.contentfulClient.getEntries({
    //^^^^  return promise to next `then()`
```